# How to figure out why VS hangs?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Suggestion from a work colleague - when VS is very very slow or is hanging:

> Open a second copy of VS and attach
>   its debugger to the first copy. When
>   the first copy hangs, pause it in the
>   second copy and look at the call
>   stack..

I thought it was a cool idea... but would am I missing something here? Are there any pitfalls with this approach?  Or does anyone have an even better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a completely reasonable way to determine why Visual Studio, or any other application for that matter, is hanging or unresponsive.  I used it frequently when I worked on the Visual Studio team.